# Check if device has a camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

In my app, I'd like to use the camera, if the device has one. Are there any devices running android that *do not* have a camera? By including the following into my manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

then it's basically saying "I'll use a camera if one exists, but don't need one to run the app".

How could I check if a camera exists on the device, before attempting to use the Camera class?

Comment: I believe (but I'm not 100% sure) that all past and present versions of the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](http://source.android.com/compatibility/) specify a camera with some minimum resolution.  Complying with the CDD is a prerequisite for licensed access to the Android Market and proprietary Google applications.  There are Android devices out there that don't, though (e.g. the Nook color).

Comment: As of today, the current version of the document (4.2) specifies "Device implementations SHOULD include a rear-facing camera, and MAY include a front-facing camera." Note that it does not use the keyword 'MUST'.

Comment: Just to add that there's also devices that only have a front-facing camera.

Comment: Is there a point in adding this to the manifest, if it says that the app should work with and without a camera? Does it affect the app on the Play Store, perhaps?

Answer (score -45, accepted):

I've not tried it, but:

```
private android.hardware.Camera mCameraDevice;

try {
  mCameraDevice = android.hardware.Camera.open();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "fail to connect Camera", e);
  // Throw exception
}
```

May be what you need.

Comment: And don't forget to release the Camera object!

Comment: See dpjanes answer below for the correct way to see if a device has a camera.

Comment: Bad approach. Expensive call. If the same camera is opened by other applications, this will throw a RuntimeException. Doesn't suit purpose.

Comment: This answer has become so famous! :)
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316273/651647

Comment: This implementation on Android 6.0 (API Level 23) +  would throw a SecurityException unless you had specifically requested the "android.permission.CAMERA" permission at runtime.

Comment: This answer solved my issue with rooted Android TV box. The ones telling me to use package manager does not.

Comment: This would work but It is bad practice to use exceptions to determine code logic flow.

Answer (score 228):

This is what I'm using

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
}
```

All sorts of other fun things to test for are available too - the compass, is location available, is there a front facing camera:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Comment: so quick question. this might be dumb but i am new to android/java
where do you get context from???? thanks

Comment: @grobartn: `public class YourActivity extends Activity { Context contextActivity; PackageManager pm; @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... contextActivity = this; pm = contextActivity.getPackageManager(); ...`

Comment: From API level 9, you may want to check for FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT besides FEATURE_CAMERA. For example, Nexus 7 (which has only one frontal camera) returns false to FEATURE_CAMERA.

Comment: For Kindle Fire HD 7" (Android 4.0.3), I found that it reports FEATURE_CAMERA, even though it only has a front camera!  Awful ... as a workaround I also test (FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT and Camera.getNumberOfCameras() == 1) then I know there is no rear camera.

Comment: After API level 17, you can use PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me with KitKat through the emulator at least (I don't have a KitKat device without a camera to test). I have the emulator set for no front and no back camera but this tells me there is a camera. The answer below which counts the number of cameras does work though -- it returns 0.

Answer (score 43):

To find out how many cameras are available on your device, you can call:

```
import android.hardware.Camera;

int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
if (numCameras > 0) {
  hasCamera = true;
}
```

Camera.getNumberOfCameras() is static, so it doesn't require actually connecting to a camera. This works since API 9.

Edit:

With the newer camera2 API, you can also call [CameraManager.getCameraIdList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#getCameraIdList()), which gives a list of the all the valid camera IDs, instead of just the count.

Comment: this worked for me and the FEATURE_CAMERA did not in API 19

Comment: One line version :
boolean hasCam = android.hardware.Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 0;

Comment: This answer is better. hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) returns false on Kit-Kat (Nexus 7)

Comment: It returns false for Nexus 7 (2013), because FEATURE_CAMERA is only about back-facing cameras (due to backwards compatibility); FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY is the feature that is true if there's at least one camera of any sort on the device.

Comment: Why is `android.hardware.Camera` deprecated? What should be used instead for this function? I know we now have `android.hardware.camera2` , but where can we find the alternative to `getNumberOfCameras` there?

Answer (score 12):

you should use this to find camera in your device

```
public static boolean isCameraAvailable(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the most useful one. FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY is a good choice. Here is a shorter version of the code for those who prefer it.
    `public static  boolean isCameraAvailable(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) 
}`

Answer (score 7):

Camera.getNumberOfCameras() is deprecated. You can use:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public int getNumberOfCameras() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        try {
            return ((CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE)).getCameraIdList().length;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e("", "", e);
        }
    }
    return Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the ***PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()*** method for checking Camera  :

```
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Answer (score 3):

by following way we can check does device has camera or not.

```
/** Check if this device has a camera */
    public static boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

For front camera

```
    Context context = this;
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {

        Utils.makeAlertDialog(context, "Has Front Camera ?", "YES");

    } else {

        Utils.makeAlertDialog(context, "Has Front Camera ?", "NO");
          }
```

for back camera

```
    Context context = this;
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

        Utils.makeAlertDialog(context, "Has back Camera ?", "YES");

    } else {

        Utils.makeAlertDialog(context, "Has back Camera ?", "NO");
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
```

from : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Answer (score 2):

As per Android documentation :

```
/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
```

Refer more about the camera API : 
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#detect-camera

Answer (score 2):

it is better to check ANY camera on the device since it could be external camera as well

```
packageManager.hasSystemFeature(FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)
```

Documentation:

> Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures and hasSystemFeature: The
> device has at least one camera pointing in some direction, or can
> support an external camera being connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android 2.3, there are some APIs that you can check your camera status, such as the number of cameras (front and back)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#detect-camera), you have to use Package Manager to check if Camera is available on the device or not

**In Java:**

```
final boolean isCameraAvailable = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

**In Kotlin:**

```
val isCameraAvailable = packageManager.hasSystemFeature(FEATURE_CAMERA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in android tv boxes where you can plug and play usb camera a number of times. At some point of time, The camera service starts saying that it detected one camera in the system while no camera is connected to the system. This happens when you plug in/out the camera a number of times. To fix that, I found this solution working:

```
//under oncreate:
//cameraManager = ((CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE)); 

public int getNumberOfCameras() {
        int count_ = 0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            try {
                count_ = cameraManager.getCameraIdList().length;

                if(count_==1)
                {
                    try {
                        cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0]);
                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        count_ = 0;
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
               //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            count_ = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        }

        return count_;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
public static boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
}
```

Put this method in your Utils.java project class.