# How do I exclude devices with no rear facing camera?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an app ready to go that requires that there be a rear facing camera. Obviously it has the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` permission in the manifest but this does not rule out devices such as the Nexus 7 tablet which has only a front facing camera.

Short of going through and manually excluding the devices how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know of a programmatical answer.
As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399333/detecting-lack-of-rear-camera) indicates, you can use

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

This returns false if the device has no back facing camera (so false on the Nexus 7)

the flag

```
FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT
```

will still be true instead. So you can use this test on launch of your first activity, along with a big warning in your app description.

However, I don't know of a way to use the manifest to exclude the devices on this criteria, short of manually excluding devices.

Edit: another question linked as related points out this uses-feature flag for the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

According to the docs:

> The application uses the device's camera. If the device supports multiple cameras, the application uses the camera that facing away from the screen.

So it's a bit ambiguous for front-facing only devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use uses-feature tag  given inandroid. You have  to declare this tag in manifest file. It automatically filter the device based on given condtion. Just use this uses-feature tag in manifest like this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

For more detail follow the following links:-
[Android Uses Premission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: Even if you do not use android:required="true", the Google Play system assumes that this is a required property and filters on that basis.