# How to Check if a feature is available in Android

Tags: android

Quick Question:

Where can I find or check if a certain feature (Bluetooth, NFC, WiFi, GPS, ...) is present in an Android device?

For a simpler example: If the device doesn't have a Bluetooth available (ie: There is no bluetooth). Is there a way to check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if device has a camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944117/check-if-device-has-a-camera)