# App is published on Play Store but doesn't show up on Tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play

I have published an app on Google Play Store but when I try to download it on Tablet, it says, app is not compatible.

Also, in developer console, I get this message: **Your layout should make use of the available space on 7-inch tablets**

Now, 1st thing , I want to lock app to **only portrait** orientation and hence screen usage will be almost same.

Here's [the link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appmix.propertynotes) of the app.

Some imp info about the app:

- android:minSdkVersion="10"
- android:largeScreens="true" **AND** android:xlargeScreens="true"

To support Tablets, android docs says, check if `minSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher.` , but what if I want to support **devices with OS 2.3.3** ?

Please give appropriate advice.

### Edit

Is this ok?

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"  android:required="false"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

### Edit 2

After updating permissions part of manifest file as following, app is showing up in tabs also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: forget about the misSdkVersion because i have an app in the market which support 2.2 and it support tablets as well. do u have layout-xlarge or layout-sw720dp in your res folder?

Comment: **layout-large** is there but no **layout-xlarge**. Also **layout-large** don't have layout for all screens of app

Comment: check with sdkversions maximum & target sdks used in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: @OsamaEspil & AnilKumar - values of both **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** for my app are **10**. Will that do?

Comment: @GAMA The link to your app is down. Did you remove it or Google suspended it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it says, app is not compatible.

It is showing error on device not only because minSDKversion but also google play concern about your given permission on the manifest file as well.

Like if you entered something like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Your tab will not support it.

So instead of using `uses-permission` use  `<uses-feature>`. And in java file check for it that your needed hardware is available or not.

For `<uses-feature>` see the below link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference

**Edited:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"  android:required="false"/>
```

Nope you can't give permission like this because `uses-permission` not allowed android:required="false". Although It will not through any error it will not work.

If you will use `<uses-feature>` it will take the permission to access the specific hardware.

So use this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

**And not to forget to check this feature availability in your java code. If you will not check it, CAMERA, SEND_SMS wont work in your app.**

To check camera availability use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5266165/):

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
   // Do you camera work here.
}
```

Comment: Or that implies, I can **REPLACE** `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` with `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />` and so on OR I'll need **BOTH** ?

Comment: No just keep one i.e. <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

Comment: No, if I remove <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> *and just keep* <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" /> , I get exception: **unable to connect to camera service**. If I keep both, it's working...

Comment: Check my answer i have mentioned "not to forget to check this feature availability in your java code. If you will not check it, CAMERA, SEND_SMS wont work in your app."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40957/discussion-between-andru-and-gama)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by checking. I do check like this `if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
 .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY))`. But if I don't add permission tag and just add features tag, it doesn't work **even though device have SMS support**. So, I geuss both are required,refer this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Comment: Yap sorry for confusion. You have to declare the both.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I have made the changes and uploaded new version on Play Store. I'll let you know if it works as uploading might take few minutes/hours.

Comment: Yap. Hope that will help you.

Comment: Ok. Also,values of both **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** for my app are **10**. Will that do?

Comment: Make android:minSdkVersion="8" if your other java code dont need the upper version.

Comment: I'm more concerned about **targetSdkVersion**. As android documentation says, for tablet compatibility check *minSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher* ?