# Why google play store is not showing the reason for device unavailability for app?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I am mobile application developer and working on native as well as Phone Gap also.

I have build one application in Phonegap that work perfectly in device but not working in some of the tabs.

That i found here as per the [Google Play Store policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017). But why they are not showing a reason that due to some these kind of invalid code or due to some specific error which Google not allow you to run on some specific device.

**Query 1 :** I have Samsung Galaxy tab 2 and tab 3. My app is not working in both tablet as per the unsupported device availability list and when user search from tablets then they can't find app also in play store.

In my app i have set all requirements for all devices and tablets as below ,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my_pkg" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.5" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />


    <application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="my_pkg.AlarmReceiver">
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="my_pkg.AlarmRestoreOnBoot">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="my_pkg.MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So, I am stuck here what is the issue with my app and why Google store is not allow to install my app in some of the device and tablet.

Before a week the total number of unsupported device & tablets are 1550 and now that are 1153.

**Query 2 :** How can i found the mistakes due to which i am not able to run my app in tablets and how to resolve it?.

Please Help me how to resolve this issue because without knowing the reason how can i solve it.

Comment: which type of permissions you have taken and features you have used in your application?

Comment: I'm not sure but I could imagine that phonegap uses some binary files, and maybe that files are not compatible (wrong architecture) with that devices.

Comment: JUST SEE THIS ANSWER here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905531/app-is-published-on-play-store-but-doesnt-show-up-on-tablets/19905748#19905748

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally after spending long time on RnD i have found solution. Actually i am not solo founder for this answer. I really thanks to all who had helped me to solve this issue.

Divesh Salian's answer is very near. I tried as per his instruction and along with that I have alter my `config.xml` file which have some unnecessary  `<features></features>` tags.

I have asked my question in [Samsung Developer form](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=248303) and also tried test my app in RTL but i was not able to login in web browser, don't know why ?

and finally I applied some other alternative regarding `<uses-feature></uses-feature>`

```
 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.input_methods"
        android:required="false" />
```

I have use above features but not going to filter app base on that so i have set `android:required="false"` for some specific features.

**Care below things if you find this type of problem**

- [How Google play filter the apps ?](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)
- [Is your Uses-Feature are required ?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering)
- [is your version code valid ?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)
- [Is your app compatible with all screen?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)
- [Have you added permission which are not required for your apps ?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)

I hope these links will solve your problem definitely.

Thanks to all again !!!

Comment: It's Awesome Answer This answer reduce lots of developer issue and also satisfy there issue !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in your manifest file, Previously it had worked for me

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 near to my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to decipher the problem, create a Samsung Developers account and submit your app. Their engineers will test the app on different devices(phone and tablet) and give you a detailed report and a video of whatever issue they encounter while testing the app.

I'm sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks +1, Your suggestion was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try and run on the app via Android emulator and check the log cat for errors.

Secondly if the app was built with HTML5 and Javascript, try and validate the html tags and check your javascript functions.

Ensure you that have null values for some certain fields. Add console messages in your javascript functions to validate all the values the app needs.

Example:

```
function TestMe() {

var a1 = document.getElementById("textboxname").value;

console.log(a1); //this line is to show that you don't have a null value.

}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already put the console message in my js function. Next is i have validate my whole code in JSHint , and Major thing is my app is working perfectly in same tablet (samsung tab2 & tab3) from system but that is not showing in playstore if user open from tablet.

Comment: Thanks again. but not need to add new answer you can update older one so please remove that otherwise someone will give you down vote. Let me try your answer. Thanks