# Unable to install app from google play in Android Tablet

Tags: android-manifest, android-permissions, google-play

we have uploaded a greeting appplication in play store. it working fine in mobiles. but in tablets i am getting the error as "this device is not compatible with this version". 
here is my android manifest permission. please check it and let me know if any one fine the mistake .

```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<permission
    android:name="com.techvedika.holacards.Activity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.techvedika.holacards.Activity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Is it mandatory to have android:targetsdkversion to find the app in google play??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484209/play-store-reports-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-but-it-insta  this will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a filtering issue. Just add it in your manifest file :

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
```

For reference, [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947084/why-google-play-store-is-not-showing-the-reason-for-device-unavailability-for-ap).

Comment: chk this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484209/play-store-reports-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-but-it-insta

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I havenot used uses-feature i have used every feature in <uses-permission in this attribute only , so no need of giving android:required="false". Is it mandatory to mention android:name="android.hardware.camera" in <uses-feature> only?

Comment: When a user searches or browses for apps to download on Google Play, the results are filtered based on which applications are compatible with the device. For example, if an app requires a camera, Google Play would not show the app to devices that do not have a camera.

Comment: you are correct but google play will filters the app if we used any feature in the "<uses-feature>" this tag only. i have used "<uses-permission>" Tag. u can check the question again.and i am not using camera , i am just using the camera intent and i added that permission in <uses-permission> in this tag only. we dnt need to mention android:required="false" for <uses-permission> @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: No that's not true. if you dont use the tag "<uses-feature>", it'll take its default value i.e. required="true" for the hardware permission you have given in the manifest. In your case you've set Camera permission.

Comment: @AndroidDev YEs,TheLittleNaruto is right. google will take default as true base on the given permission, so it would be batter to make false if google is not allowing to install in specific device. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947084/why-google-play-store-is-not-showing-the-reason-for-device-unavailability-for-ap

Comment: @chintan khetiya did i written anything in uses -feature?? first see the question and give the comment. pls avoid the false comments.

Comment: Yeah thats we are talking that add uses -feature and make default "false" otherwise google will read as "true". okay leave it, i don't care , me and @TheLittleNaruto are helping you & you are not taking seriously.Its your choice BTW answer is right.