# my android app is not visible in google play store for some devices.?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-market-filtering

I published my application yesterday. After a few hours I check on the Google Play store website and it was there. I checked it and downloaded it into my phone. But two of my friends who uses Samsung Galaxy handsets do not see it published application on Google Play store. and when they try to download it with direct link google play shows this message "your device is not compatible with this version".

- the same phones was able to run the application with no problem when i send it by email. 
  can any one help me please????

Answer (score 2):

Use `<uses-feature>` instead of `<uses-permission>` in your manifest file & set `android:required="false"` for some specific features which are not necessary to use application.

When you use something like GPS or camera, Google Play takes this as a needed feature to use the application when maybe your app can run even if you don't have GPS on your device, so, you can exclude all or some of these features by adding these lines in the manifest file like below.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location"         android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"     android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"      android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"           android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi"             android:required="false" />
```

These way, you are telling them that these features are not needed in order to use the app. Be sure then, to control this inside your app, for example, if you don't require camera, maybe you should check for it before using it.

**Care below things if you find this type of problem:**

[How Google play filter the apps ?](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

[Is your Uses-Feature are required ?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering)

[is your version code valid ?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

[Is your app compatible with all screen?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

[Have you added permission which are not required for your apps ?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)

I hope these links will solve your problem.

Comment: have you used camera functionality in your application .

Comment: set `android:required="false"` for some specific features which are not necessary to use application. So, google play will not filter device based on that feature. So, application will also display in device even if device doesn't support that feature.

Comment: How do you check for telephone permissions?

Comment: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"             android:required="false" />` See this link for more details http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference

Answer (score 0):

This is from developers.android.com :

- Google Play applies filters to control which Android devices can
  download your application from the store.
- Filtering ensures that your apps are available only to users whose
  devices meet your app's compatibility requirements.
- Filtering is determined by the configuration requirements that you
  declare in you app's manifest file, as well as other factors.

You should check out this article [Google Play Filters](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

Comment: If the minimum SDK is larger than the phone SDK, will it just not show up in the play store itself? Also, would these permissions be good? Do I need to add anything? 
http://snag.gy/Bo7Cv.jpg

Comment: It won't show in incompatible device. Also those permissions look good. No issue there.

Comment: So is it a problem with the SDK or a problem with the `<uses-permission`? How do I tell?

Comment: If you set Minimum SDK to a larger version than the one in the phone, it will not show. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I asked that question here in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170901/app-not-showing-up?noredirect=1#comment56089590_34170901 **So what should I do for the phone state permission, because that may not work on tablets...Is there a way I can check if the device has the ability of a phone?**

Answer (score 0):

First check the Sdk version in manifest here: **android:minSdkVersion=""**

If its greater than your device sdk version then decrease it. And remove this line: `android:minSdkVersion=""` if there in manifest and also check this answer.

[App is published on Play Store but doesn't show up on Tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905531/app-is-published-on-play-store-but-doesnt-show-up-on-tablets/19905748#19905748)

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried the below links from your friends mobile browser

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename
```

as mentioned in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910156/android-app-is-published-but-not-visible-anywhere-in-google-play)