# App not showing up?

Tags: java, android, string, permissions, android-manifest

**My app isn't showing up on google play store for some phones, like the `Samsung GT-S5830i`** I don't know whether it is because of my `<uses-permission>` or my `min SDK` or my Screen Size permissions.

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905531/app-is-published-on-play-store-but-doesnt-show-up-on-tablets/19905748#19905748) I made all of my `<uses-permission>` into `<uses-feature>` and added `android:required="false"` to every permission. **Now, I need to check feature availability in my java code since the permissions are optional, so that I can avoid a `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial`** How would I do that in my following permissions:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"  />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false"/>
```

I'm pretty sure that all phones and tablets can go through with my permissions, so I don't even think that I need to make it `feature` and add the `required="false"`. If it is not the permissions, it could be the Screen Size permissions.

Should I do something like this in my manifest?

```
 <compatible-screens>
            <screen
                android:screenDensity="ldpi"
                android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Currently, I have this:

```
   <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Could it be because of the SDK?

Thanks for telling me whether it is because of the **permissions, the SDK, or the screen size**, and what I should do to keep some of the permissions optional,

Ruchir

Comment: `min-sdk` is 11 right now

Comment: I don't think its min SDK problem. I had never written the <support-screens> tag in manefiest file. I'm sure it works on all device if u remove the <support-screens> tag and change back <uses-feature> to <uses-permission>.

Comment: @kevz Then why doesn't it show up on play store for that particular phone?

Comment: Have u tested ur app on that device? Coz there might be min sdk problem stated by Vivid Vervet.

Comment: @kevz I can't test it on that device because I can't even see the app on the play store! :)

Comment: I mean locally from studios not play store.

Comment: @kevz You mean by plugging it in my computer and installing the APK through android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from comment your min-sdk level is 11, that means your app needs minimum of andriod 3.0 (Honeycomb) and the phone you're tested is **[samsung GT-s5830i](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_ace_s5830i-4664.php)** which comes with android froyo, (version 2.2) and it's API level is 8, so it wont be displayed in playstore for that device. to support for that phone you have decrement your minimum api level, read about API level and os version from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html). and read [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) link to know more about play store filtering

Comment: But shouldn't it still show up in play store...? Isn't it like I can **see** the app, but can't install it? Shouldn't the user just see a message like this: 
http://snag.gy/M8C8A.jpg

Comment: Also, how do you know its API level is 8?

Comment: click on the link on the answer, see its os is android froyo

Comment: you cant install the app since your minimum api level is 11 and you are trying to install it in a device which has api level 8

Comment: Yeah, I _can't install it_, but shouldn't I still be able to _see_ it in the Play Store?

Comment: may be you have more than one device associated with your account, and the other devices may have api version greater than 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97361/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-vivid-vervet).