# How to allow installation of .apk file for Non Telephony devices on google play

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application in which, I have added telephony permission but i want this application to visible for non telephony device on google play.

Comment: have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905531/app-is-published-on-play-store-but-doesnt-show-up-on-tablets/19905748#19905748

Comment: Thanks Avijit , my problem is resolved now.