# How to check is there camera installed in the device or not?

Tags: android

This is my code. I want to select an image from either camera or gallery.
For this i have to check the camera support feature of a device.

```
  public void selectImage() {
            final String[] items = new String[]{"Camera", "Gallery"};
            final Integer[] icons = new Integer[]{R.drawable.ic_camera, R.drawable.ic_gallery};
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapterWithIcon(getActivity(), items, icons);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Select Picture")
                    .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {
                                if (//here i want to check is there mobile exists camera or not) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                } 
                            } else if (items[item].equals("Gallery")) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setType("image/*");
                                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);

                            }
                        }
                    }).show();

        }
```

I have tried a lot but no success.

Comment: Check these solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/5266165/3946958

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.hardware.Camera;`
```

Use `Camera.getNumberOfCameras();`. If it **returns** value greater than **0**, it means your device has a camera.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to show gallery to pick image from:

```
private void showGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
}
```

---

Use this to open camera (checks if device has camera or not):

```
private void showCamera() {
        // get the package manager and check if device has camera
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            // ensure that there is some activity to handle camera intents
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 5678);
            }
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(mView, "your device dont have camera", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

NOTE: Make sure you declare permission for Camera in the manifest as:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

For more details, check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) out.

Comment: your method is also works for me but i wan't the simple one. only 1 or 2 line code. means like true or false.

Comment: Yes. So you only need the if-else from `showCamera()`.